# Using Migrate Plus API to select items from a JSON array

Tags: migrations

Im novice in drupal i'm i need to solve the following error in my migration import.

For Example, nid:

```
[
    {
       nid: [
           {
             value: "110538"
           }
       ],
       uuid: [
           {
             value: "a90278c4-8bac-4539-b0c7-a6f62ed11975"
           }
       ],
       vid: [
          {
            value: "110595"
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

What sort of field selector is needed to get `nid` value?

Im have the following migrate:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: https://example.com/rest/article
  ids:
    nid:
      type: integer
  item_selector: /
  fields:
    -
      name: nid
      label: 'Nid'
      selector: nid
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Title'
      selector: /title
  constants:
    source_base_path: 'https://example.com/'
process:
  nid: nid
  title: title
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'article'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies: null
```

when i'm trying run the migration import, has occurred the following error:

```
 [warning] array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! EntityStorageBase.php:264
 [warning] Illegal offset type ContentEntityStorageBase.php:955
 [warning] Illegal offset type in isset or empty EntityStorageBase.php:250

In Connection.php line 729:

  Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values.
```

Comment: I think your item selector is off

Comment: Hello Kevin, I do not understand what you mean, you could be more specific please.